# How to have a JSON data through a "complex architecture"

Tags: javascript, json

I work with an API that returns a rather particular JSON file ...
It's been 2 days that I try to do something but I can not do it, that's why I leave it to you :)

First of all my JSON file looks like:

```
[ 
    {
        "_id": 14080,
        "name": "Amulette Séculaire",
        "lvl": "200",
        "type": "Amulette",
        "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/200/1230.png",
        "url": "https://www.dofus.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/equipements/14080-amulette-seculaire",
        "description": "Finalement, le secteur de la bijouterie n'a pas tellement évolué ces cent dernières années.",
        "stats": [
            {
                "Vitalité": {
                    "from": "251",
                    "to": "300"
                }
            },
            {
                "Intelligence": {
                    "from": "61",
                    "to": "80"
                }
            },
            {
                "Agilité": {
                    "from": "16",
                    "to": "25"
                }
            },
            {
                "Sagesse": {
                    "from": "31",
                    "to": "40"
                }
            },
            {
                "PA": {
                    "from": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "Prospection": {
                    "from": "16",
                    "to": "20"
                }
            },
            {
                "Dommages Feu": {
                    "from": "8",
                    "to": "12"
                }
            },
            {
                "Dommages Air": {
                    "from": "8",
                    "to": "12"
                }
            },
            {
                "% Résistance Neutre": {
                    "from": "6",
                    "to": "8"
                }
            },
            {
                "% Résistance Feu": {
                    "from": "6",
                    "to": "8"
                }
            },
            {
                "Résistance Critiques": {
                    "from": "11",
                    "to": "15"
                }
            }
        ],
        "condition": [],
        "recipe": [
            {
                "Galet brasillant": {
                    "id": "12740",
                    "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/12740-galet-brasillant",
                    "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/15289.w48h48.png",
                    "type": "Galet",
                    "lvl": "150",
                    "quantity": "3"
                }
            },
            {
                "Poudre glaciale": {
                    "id": "13154",
                    "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/13154-poudre-glaciale",
                    "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/48292.w48h48.png",
                    "type": "Poudre",
                    "lvl": "190",
                    "quantity": "7"
                }
            },
            {
                "Poil d'aisselle de Missiz Frizz": {
                    "id": "13935",
                    "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/13935-poil-aisselle-missiz-frizz",
                    "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/54691.w48h48.png",
                    "type": "Poil",
                    "lvl": "200",
                    "quantity": "9"
                }
            },
            {
                "Pédoncule de Mérulor": {
                    "id": "13978",
                    "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/13978-pedoncule-merulor",
                    "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/119008.w48h48.png",
                    "type": "Champignon",
                    "lvl": "200",
                    "quantity": "6"
                }
            },
            {
                "Œil de Cycloïde": {
                    "id": "13988",
                    "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/13988-oeil-cycloide",
                    "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/109603.w48h48.png",
                    "type": "Œil",
                    "lvl": "200",
                    "quantity": "30"
                }
            },
            {
                "Queue de Sinistrofu": {
                    "id": "13991",
                    "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/13991-queue-sinistrofu",
                    "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/65764.w48h48.png",
                    "type": "Queue",
                    "lvl": "200",
                    "quantity": "3"
                }
            },
            {
                "Bandelette du Comte Harebourg": {
                    "id": "13995",
                    "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/13995-bandelette-comte-harebourg",
                    "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/15831.w48h48.png",
                    "type": "Ressources diverses",
                    "lvl": "200",
                    "quantity": "1"
                }
            },
            {
                "Œil de verre": {
                    "id": "14145",
                    "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/14145-oeil-verre",
                    "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/109604.w48h48.png",
                    "type": "Œil",
                    "lvl": "200",
                    "quantity": "1"
                }
            }
        ],
        "setId": 271
    }
]
```

For the moment i extract data like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
            petsTable = {
                name: pets[i].name,
                level: pets[i].lvl,
                type: pets[i].type,
                description: pets[i].description,
                imgUrl: pets[i].imgUrl,
                url: pets[i].url,
                condition: pets[i].condition,
                recipe: pets[i].recipe
            };
```

and to go on recipe i use an array :

```
var petsRecipe = [];

for (var x = 0; x < petsTable.recipe.length; x++) {
    petsRecipe.push(petsTable.recipe[x]);
}
```

This array result : 
**Array(8) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]**

And an example of the first Object is :

```
0:
Galet brasillant:
id: "12740"
imgUrl: "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/15289.w48h48.png"
lvl: "150"
quantity: "3"
type: "Galet"
url: "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/...
```

But I can not collect the id or the "lvl", have you ideas ?
Thanks for your help

Comment: What data do you want to access from this json? what code have you tried?

Comment: *"that's why I leave it to you :)"* - We'd love to help you *debug your attempts*, however the purpose of StackOverflow isn't to have others write your code after you've given up. Consider editing your question to include some attempts/code.

Comment: "_Is what I am doing wrong?_"   How can we know? You didn't show us anything!

Comment: `response[0].recipe` is an array containing objects. Each of those has a single key which you can get via `Object.keys(obj)[0]`.

Comment: i've edited my post :)

Comment: Is there a particular format you want your resulting data to be in? ie. you want an object? 2 arrays for lvls and ids? does `petsRecipe.map(function(x) { return { lvl: x.lvl, id: x.id }})` suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the `recipe` array is that every object it contains has a structure like this :

```
{
    "Poudre glaciale": {
        "id": "13154",
        "lvl": "190",
        "quantity": "7"
    }
}
```

In other words, each object has one key (with a different name each time), and the object you want to reach is nested under this variable key, which makes it tricky to reach.

You can access the key name ("poudre glaciale") using `Object.keys(obj)[0]`. Then you can reach the sub-object easily :

```js
const recipe = [{
    "Galet brasillant": {
      "id": "12740",
      "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/12740-galet-brasillant",
      "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/15289.w48h48.png",
      "type": "Galet",
      "lvl": "150",
      "quantity": "3"
    }
  },
  {
    "Poudre glaciale": {
      "id": "13154",
      "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/13154-poudre-glaciale",
      "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/48292.w48h48.png",
      "type": "Poudre",
      "lvl": "190",
      "quantity": "7"
    }
  },
  {
    "Poil d'aisselle de Missiz Frizz": {
      "id": "13935",
      "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/13935-poil-aisselle-missiz-frizz",
      "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/54691.w48h48.png",
      "type": "Poil",
      "lvl": "200",
      "quantity": "9"
    }
  },
  {
    "Pédoncule de Mérulor": {
      "id": "13978",
      "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/13978-pedoncule-merulor",
      "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/119008.w48h48.png",
      "type": "Champignon",
      "lvl": "200",
      "quantity": "6"
    }
  },
  {
    "Œil de Cycloïde": {
      "id": "13988",
      "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/13988-oeil-cycloide",
      "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/109603.w48h48.png",
      "type": "Œil",
      "lvl": "200",
      "quantity": "30"
    }
  },
  {
    "Queue de Sinistrofu": {
      "id": "13991",
      "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/13991-queue-sinistrofu",
      "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/65764.w48h48.png",
      "type": "Queue",
      "lvl": "200",
      "quantity": "3"
    }
  },
  {
    "Bandelette du Comte Harebourg": {
      "id": "13995",
      "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/13995-bandelette-comte-harebourg",
      "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/15831.w48h48.png",
      "type": "Ressources diverses",
      "lvl": "200",
      "quantity": "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "Œil de verre": {
      "id": "14145",
      "url": "https://www.dofus-touch.com/fr/mmorpg/encyclopedie/ressources/14145-oeil-verre",
      "imgUrl": "https://s.ankama.com/www/static.ankama.com/dofus/www/game/items/52/109604.w48h48.png",
      "type": "Œil",
      "lvl": "200",
      "quantity": "1"
    }
  }
]

const output = recipe.map( obj => {
     let keyName = Object.keys(obj)[0]; // "Galet brasillant", "poudre glaciale", etc.
     
     return obj[keyName]; // the object containing attributes
})

console.log(output[0])
```

**Edit :**

If you want the id of "Poudre glaciale", you have to do this :

First, filter the `recipe` array to keep only the object you want : `recipe.filter( obj => Object.keys(obj)[0] === "Poudre glaciale")`

Then, extract the first (and only) object from this filtered array with `[0]`

Then enter inside the `"Poudre glaciale"` key with `["Poudre glaciale"]`

And then you can access the `id`

So the full solution :

```
const id = recipe.filter( obj => Object.keys(obj)[0] === "Poudre glaciale")[0]["Poudre glaciale"].id
```

Comment: what is the best way to get the id of "poudre glaciale" for exemple?

Comment: thank you, and to do it dynamically, should have replace "Poudre glaciale" by the keyName ?